# How to get locations of Google Maps Route?

Tags: json, google-maps

How I can get coordinates (lat,lon)  of route from url generated by google (like: http://goo.gl/maps/1gpxk).
Is there an API for that  or anything else?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

See the documentation. Make sure you read the [Terms of Service](https://developers.google.com/maps/faq#tos).

- [Directions Web service](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/)
- [Google Maps Javascript API v3 Directions Service](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions)

Comment: PLease, can you give an example?

Comment: There are examples in the documentation.